# How many strictly increasing functions $[4] \to [12]$ precede $(2,3,4,5)$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

Notation: Let $[n]$ denote the set $\{1,...,n\}$ and we will represent a function $[k]\to[n]$ as a list: $(f(1),f(2),...,f(k))$

The question is:

> Consider all strictly increasing functions $[4] \to [14]$ and order them with the natural lexicographic order induced by the order in $[14]$. How many functions precede the function $(2,3,4,5)$?
>
> - $13 \choose 4$
> - $13 \choose 3$
> - $14 \choose 4$
> - $15 \choose 3$
> - $14 \choose 3$

If this wasn't a multiple choice question I would just simply try to count them, but seeing the options and seeing that they are all formulated with binomial coefficients I arrived at the conclusion that there must be a simpler way to solve this than just count all possible functions. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that out of the tuples that start with $2$. one has that $(2,3,4,5)$ is the smallest one. So you want to count the ones that start with $1$ and that would be all of them, so choose out of $13$ numbers the $3$ you will place after $1$ say $x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that $1<x_2<x_3<x_4$ in $\binom{13}{3}$ ways.

Comment: so $14 \choose 4$ is the total number of increasing functions, and $13 \choose 3$ is the number of function greater than $(2,3,4,5)$, and thus ${14 \choose 4} - {13 \choose 3}$ is the answer?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Oh sorry, I read it backwards. I read it as if you want it to count the ones bigger than. My bad. I have edited it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Let me just ask one more question: If instead of functions that precede $(2,3,4,5)$ we wanted functions that precede $(2,6,8,9)$, for example, how would you count the functions between $(2,3,4,5)$ and $(2,6,8,9)$?

Comment: I would count the ones starting on $3,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and $2,y_2,y_3,y_4$ with $y_2>6$(cause the one there is the last one, so out of $14-6$ choose 3) and substract. For the ones in between I would count the ones before the min and after the max and substract.